# How to convert Key Value list into array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a list of key value pairs like such

```
{
    apple: "Apple",
    banana: "Banana"
}
```

And I would like to convert this into Object like such

```
[
    {key: 'apple', value: 'Apple'},
    {key: 'banana', value: 'Banana'}
]
```

Do I just have to make a loop to do this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method to get a key-value pair array and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to iterate and create a customized array.

```js
let obj = {
    apple: "Apple",
    banana: "Banana"
};

let res =Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value }))

console.log(res)
```